# How to use custom code to add Excel-like "color scale" conditional formatting to SSRS report

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I am trying to use this custom code in SSRS

`public function ColorScaleRYG(value, minValue, maxValue) as string`

in a custom code in ssrs
and then in a Fill expression

`=Code.ColorScaleRYG(Sum(Fields!SalesAmount.Value), 0, 100000)`

which should break my values in a group and assign shades of colors from red(0) to green(max valer).
But for some reason nothing happens/ 
What am I missing?
I need something like that:
[image]

Comment: Share the function code (if any). Also you can try using the `=Code.ColorScaleRYG(Sum(Fields!SalesAmount.Value), 0, 100000)` as value in the textboxes and see what the function is returnning for debugging purpose.

Comment: what expect output ?

Answer (score 0):

I wont be able to give you the specific answer as it is with your code, however this is how I go about it.

In Design Mode I Right click the required Cell and Select "**Text Box Properties**.

I then go to the **Fill Tab** and click on the **expression button** next to Fill Color.

I then User something like the following code

```
=IIF(Fields!Total_Eligible.Value>100,"MidnightBlue","Silver")
```

You should be able to Stack this IIF Commands.

It is just a matter of changing the Fields! field to the approriate variable and then the conditions.

This Returns the following Values

[image]

Hope this Helps.

*Post Note - Probably dont use these colors as they aren't easy to read , I just grabbed two at random off an existing report to demonstrate.*

Comment: Thanks for that, I did that and also used a SWITCH function. But I need that for so many cells, and they all have different range of values. 
It is so easy to achieve in excel, there are gotta be a way to do the same in SSRS

Comment: SSRS is interesting like that. I probably swear at the screen 20 times a day at the moment.